# Pivot chart for totals of key value

Tags: excel, charts, pivot, pivot-table, key-value

I have a large collection of data which is formatted similar to the representation below:

```
Machine1 Name1 Product1 Quantity1 Scrap1 delaytype1 delaytype1time delaytype2 delaytype2time
Machine1 Name2 Product2 Quantity2 Scrap2
Machine2 Name3 Product3 Quantity3 Scrap3 delaytype3 delaytype3time
Machine3 Name4 Product4 Quantity4 Scrap4 delaytype1 delaytype1time delaytype2 delaytype2 time
```

Now, I have all of the data in Excel sheets, and its quite vast (several thousand sheets, dozens thousand rows combined), and I use pivot charts to graph some of the data. I want to make some charts, lets say how many pieces did each machine produce and so on, and important thing to graph nicely are the dealys. Lets say the machine1, on specific date, had three delays. There are 10 delay codes, ( code 1 is machine broken for example), so the entry would be 1 1 (first 1 means the code, second time in hours). Several delays can happen for one machine for a row, or none. So that field has flexibile length. Each code and its time are in separate cells, like in the sample data I wrote above, each text represents a cell.

Is there a way to make the pivot chart graph this but sum up the individual delays of the same type together? For example, if Machine1 had two rows, and on first had the following delays 1 1 (broken machine, 1 hour), 2 2 (no power, 2 hours), and on the second day, 2 2 (no power, 2 hours), 3 1 (no worker, 1 hour), the result would be 1 1, 2 4 (two hours from day 1, two from day 2), 3 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I resolved the issue by porting the data to specifically organized tables and generated the PivotCharts from there.